# Particular sscanf usage

Tags: c, scanf

Im using sscanf to read/parse a 3 char string into an int as:

```
char strId[4] = "123";
int i;
int count = sscanf(strId, "%i" &i);
```

Im testing `count==1` to check if the parse suceeds or fails.
`"123"` suceeds correctly - I want to consider this a number.
`"aaa"` fails correctly - I don't want to consider this a number.
but
`"2aa"` suceeds (count==1, i==2)- but I would like to identify this as a failure as I don't want to consider this a number.
**How to simply parse strId to meet the above conditions?**

Comment: Why do you need the `(const char *)` cast?

Comment: Why do you use `sscanf` and not `strtol`

Comment: Is this the exact code?

Comment: The code is simplifed - the source string is slightly more complicated, there are other extractions.

Comment: this code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char str[255];
int count = sscanf((const char*)strId, "%i%254s", &i, str);
```

if it comes back with `count == 1` it is okay?

Comment: 2 weaknesses: `&str` should be `str`. `"%i%s"` s/b `"%i%254s"`.  A simpler similar approach would be `char ch; int count = sscanf(strId, "%i %c", &i, &ch);`

Comment: My answer does answer the question and it keeps with the spirit of his code. For the record I think strtol route is a better general solution but it involves completely rewriting his code.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert Agree.  strtol is a better solution but in the real code there are other extractions - so I'd need to sscanf anyway so would need to sscanf to a buf and strtol the buf - this solutions just gets it done with the almost existing code +1 line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtol(3)`. It allows specification of an "end-of-parsing" pointer (`endptr` below). After the conversion has finished you can check wether or not it points at the end of string. If it doesn't, there were non-number characters left in the input.

```
long strtol(const char *restrict str, char **restrict endptr, int base);
```

From `man strtol`:

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first
>   invalid character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all,
>   however, strtol() stores the original value of str in *endptr.  (Thus,
>   if *str is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the entire string
>   was valid.)

Comment: The `strtol()` approach is fine, but there are a number of issues to its proper set-up and check.  `errno` should be set to 0 beforehand to detect overflow.  The `endptr` needs a check to see if it matches `str` or if it points  to an acceptable trailing `char`.  `errno` then needs to be checked.  Lastly as `int` range may not match `long` range, that needs checking.  So posting an example of `strtol()` usage is far more useful that simply referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

A `sscanf()` approach, use `"%n"`.

`"%n"` saves the location where scanning stopped.

```
char strId[4] = "123";
int n = 0
sscanf(strId, "%i %n" &i, &n);
if (n == 0 || strId[n] != '\0') Handle_ProblemInput(strId);
```

This will pass:  `"123"`, `"  123"`, `"123  "`.
And fail:  `"123a"`, `""`, `"  abc"`.
May/may not detect `int` overflow `"12345678901234567890"`.

---

[Edit]

What is nice about the `"%n"` is that it can be used with complicated formats and with formats that otherwise end with fixed text.  IOWs, simply detect if the scan made it all the way to `'\0'`?

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(buf, " %i %f %7s ,,, %c blah foo %n", ...);
if (n == 0 || buf[n] != '\0') Handle_ProblemInput(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `strtol` that's an easy task just do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char  string[] = "123xyz";
char *endptr;
int   value;

value = strtol(string, &endptr, 10);
if ((*string != '\0') && (*endptr == '\0'))
    printf("%s is a number and has no unconvertible characters", string);
/* and now 'value' contains the integer value. */
```

If you want to use `sscanf()` then this should do it too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char  string[] = "123";
int   count;
int   value;
int   length;

length = strlen(string);
if ((sscanf(string, "%d%n", &value, &count) == 1) && (count == length))
    printf("%s is a number and has no unconvertible characters", string);
/* and now 'value' contains the integer value. */
```